# SharedPreferences Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have this method :

```
private void deleteExam(String i) {

        SharedPreferences prefsContatore = getSharedPreferences("esameKey"+i, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorContatore = prefsContatore.edit();
        editorContatore.putString("esameKey"+i, "0");
        editorContatore.commit();    
}
```

Go? Can I call recursively "`esameKey`"+i?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think it's not a good way, because chances to key value override. when comes same String in "i" that time new one is override on old one. for ex: take i="aaa"; and evaluate the code.

Answer (score 2):

`getSharedPreferences` access to a file and create if it does not exist. Every time you pass a different `i` a new file is created. Create it once:

```
SharedPreferences prefsContatore = getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editorContatore = prefsContatore.edit();
```

first argument of putString is a key the second paramter is the value you want to store

```
editorContatore.putString("esameKey"+i, "0");
```

this way you are putting for every `i` the value of `0`. Is really that what you want?